# MySQL 5.1 Schema Installer

Tags: mysql, wix, nsis

I need to make an installer for a MySQL 5.1 Database, but I'm totally a noob when it comes to installers.

I've been looking at NSIS and learned a little but I don't really know how to use it to just to execute a script.

Anyone out there has experience installing database schemas in multiple computers?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't have time to figure it out but I made a batch file that executes a mysql script

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html

so batch file had this

```
cmd /c mysql -h host -u user - p < scirpt_file_in_same_folder_as_batch.sql
```

The only problem was that mysql had to be set as enviroment variable path by default.

To cancel script execution you just dont write a password when promped

hope this helps someone out there.